# How to expose PDFSharp XBrushes to be picked from GUI?

Tags: pdf, colors, graphics, pdfsharp

First time working with PDFSharp, I have a win form that enables the user to select a font and size of it for the PDF to be created. Also the app draws some rectangles on the page with currently hardcoded color like this:

```
            rect = new XRect(5, 300, 25, 15);
            gfx.DrawRectangle(XBrushes.SeaShell, rect); //SET COLOR TO RECT
            tf.Alignment = XParagraphAlignment.Center;
            tf.DrawString("No", invoiceItemsHeaderFont, XBrushes.Black, rect, 
            XStringFormats.TopLeft);
```

I want the user to be able to pick the color via a drop down. How can I load all of the colors from XBrushes. to a list and then parse it as such, this is one of the attempts:

```
        foreach(XBrushes xbrush in typeof(XBrushes)
        {
            colorsRect.Add(xbrush.ToString());
        }
```

Thank you all!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but maybe this could help someone else.

I take it you are just looking to get a collection of the different brushes?

I looked at the XBrushes class and all its public static properties seem to be brushes. You could use reflection to go through all its properties and get the values of the ones that are brushes.

Something like:

```
    public static IEnumerable<XSolidBrush> Brushes
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(XBrushes).GetProperties(System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Public | System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Static)
                .Select(p => p.GetValue(null))
                .Where(b=>b.GetType()==typeof(XSolidBrush))
                .Cast<XSolidBrush>();
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing to note is I don't think that will give you the name of the brush. The above would be good if you visually displayed the colour for the user to pick. If you need the property name you could probably just create a wrapper class that has two properties a name and the brush. You can get the property name in reflection by using p.Name. This would give you the property name as it is in thier code e.g AliceBlue rather than perhaps a more human readable version. That would give you a start you could then for example use a regex to split the camel case into individual words.